# How to disable EditText box in Android when using LongClick Listener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have `EditText` box which has focusable and `focusableontouch` enabled and all the rest are disabled in XML. The problem I am facing is that on longclick on this text box the selectAll and select pop up comes up - I would like to disable it and at the same time use the `OnlongClick` Function too..

So I tried  `android:longClickable="false"` on XML and set the text box using `LongClick` listener in java

Something like this: `edEmailId.setOnLongClickListener(myOnLongClickListener);`

Didn't work I am still getting selectALL popup window. Is LongClickable in XML and `SetOnlongClicklistener` the same?

If so how do I disable the popup?

Answer (score 0):

return true instead of false from onLongClick() in OnLongClickListener.

Comment: edEmailId.setOnLongClickListener(myOnLongClickListener);
in myOnLongClickListener while overriding onLongClick() return true if you want consume this callback, false otherwise. If you return false then os will further process this callback. In your case it is showing menu for 'select word'/'select all'.

Comment: Sorry for Delay Naresh. I tried what ever you told me but the problem is that I have long press functionality which does different things and when I set this true - the long press function doesn't happen at all..